# integrity and identity

Tags: epistemology

I have a quite straight forward question yet the answer does not appear to me as straight forward as I would like it to be. I would appreciate it, if someone could help me with the difference between integrity and identity (if there are any) ?

Comment: This is semantics, not philosophy... [Integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrity) "is the quality of being honest and having strong moral principles." [Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) has a math use as well as a philosophical one: see [Identity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity/) and [Personal identity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-personal/)

Comment: Questions about definitions of terms are off-topic on this site. Please use Wikipedia, online dictionaries, or ask on [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Integrity and identity - the basic connection**

Integrity presupposes identity. Integrity is a character-trait, a virtue, a  property of the self across time. (One can't have momentary virtues.) In other words it presupposes the continuity of a self - an intregrated self - across time that manifests, displays or exhibits integrity. This continuity is personal identity.

To the (expected) reply that a person's state at any one time is never identical with that person's state at any other time, my answer is : yes, of course, but as the concept is used personal identity requires only the continuity of such character-traits, virtues or properties as concern us. I speak here in a moral context appropriate to the question. There are extra-moral aspects of personal identity which I do not address.

**Integrity and identity - more detailed connection**

> There are different ways of characterizing the person of integrity. Such a person is usually thought of as being honest, upright
>    and loyal. Sometimes this is understood simply in terms of certain
>    types of behaviour which conform to the socially accepted code
>    of morality: he keeps his promises, he does not cheat at cards
>    or in business; he does not tell lies. Sometimes it is thought that
>    what matters is not so much adherence to an accepted code, but
>    rather that the person of integrity should do what he himself
>    thinks right, regardless of whether this coincides with the more
>    conventional view. He will be true to the standards he has come
>    to accept, stick to the principles he has evolved. The focus of
>    his honesty and loyalty will be these principles themselves, and
>    how he behaves in a social context will depend on their nature.
>    We may dislike his principles, but we admire him at least for
>    having the courage of his convictions. While on the first interpretation 'integrity' appears to be a label for a selected set of
>    moral virtues, on the second interpretation it seems rather a
>    label for a special application of these virtues, viz. honesty about
>    and loyalty to one's own principles.
>    But the notion of integrity may also be approached not by
>    picking out such moral qualities as are normally associated with
>    it, but by thinking of the person possessing integrity as being the
>    person who 'keeps his inmost self intact', whose life is 'of a piece',
>    whose self is whole and integrated. My claim is that it is this view of integrity which is the fundamental one. The person of integrity
>    keeps his self intact, and the person who lacks integrity is
>    corrupt in the sense that his self is disintegrated. (G. Taylor : 143-4 - see References.)

**References**

Christine M. Korsgaard, Self-Constitution : Agency, Identity, and Integrity, Oxford : OUP 2009. ISBN 10: 0199552800 ISBN 13: 9780199552801.

Gabriele Taylor and Raimond Gaita, 'Integrity', Proceedings of the Aristotelian Society, Supplementary Volumes, Vol. 55 (1981), pp. 143-159+161-176.

Answer (score -1):

*Identity* is how you see yourself in the world. It is really something that we think about, perhaps a concept mostly for uneducated minds: identity. But if you had to use the language of society and actions and what you associate with, then identity may be useful. Although, I feel a "good person"'s identity is more so defaulted to their actions, as making the world a better place - if we were all to converge around similar conclusions at being a good person - something that we all want. So maybe identity is what can only be unique to you, your personal history and such. Integrity is following your conscience or not I would say, when there are decisions to be made. But first, one must be aware of decisions, so it can be counted as a decision...that are potentially always at hand. So this part of integrity is relative to one's knowledge and experiences. What is an act of integrity to one is looked down upon by others perhaps. Is integrity the same for all? Is doing the *right thing* in a specific situation only 1 thing? If we were all in the same situation and did the right thing, would we do *the same thing*? If integrity is following one's conscience, then we are all have integrity because doesn't everybody really just follow their conscience? I'm not sure integrity exists. But I would say identity is what I suggested previously.

Comment: I down-voted this because it is 1) a big block of text that is hard to read even after Frank's edits 2) rambling and stream-of-consciousness in its nature and 3) because it is vague, references nothing and is mostly a reflection of your personal opinions. If you wish to improve this answer, I suggest that you 1) get the formatting in order 2) find out what you want to say **before** you write the post and 3) try to ground it something other than your personal opinions about what identity and integrity are.